# Access text inside tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

What should be added so that "Button" shows up in the red button?

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');



class Button extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: red; padding:5px;');
    shadow.appendChild(button);
  }
}
customElements.define("lol-foo", Button);
```

```html
<lol-foo>Button</lol-foo>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `textContent` to `super.textContent` that will access that property from the parent class or in you case `HTMLElement`

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');

class Button extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: red; padding:5px;');
    button.textContent = super.textContent;
    shadow.appendChild(button);
  }
}

customElements.define("lol-foo", Button);
```

```html
<lol-foo>Button</lol-foo>
```

Comment: @Cat Its a bit more flexible

Answer (score 1):

All you need to add is the `innerHTML` property of `button`:

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');
class Button extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: red; padding:5px;');
    button.innerHTML = "Button"; // Sets innerHTML
    shadow.appendChild(button);
  }
}
customElements.define("lol-foo", Button);
```

```html
<lol-foo>Button</lol-foo>
```

Alternatively, you could create a text node and add it inside of the button:

```
const text = document.createTextNode("Button");
button.appendChild(text);
shadow.appendChild(button);
```

Comment: That's the spirit friend I'm working on a api and i was stuck here thanks a trillion

Answer (score -2):

There is a difference between innerHTML and textContent (The question have been already answered, but i think that is important to understand the difference):

innerHTML:

```
<span>Hello<span>World</span></span> => returns Hello
```

textContent:

```
<span>Hello<span>World</span></span> => returns Hello World
```